# Accessing struct members

Tags: solidity, javascript, ethereumjs, struct, access

Can we access the struct member using a variable as we access in JavaScript? For example:

```
struct Abc {
     uint256 a,
     uint256 b
}

Abc xyz;

string memName = 'a';
```

I want to do something like this:

```
xyz[memName]
```

as we can do in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, the only way to access a struct member is by calling its name after the dot notation. As for your example:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.6.12;

contract Test {

   struct Abc {
     uint256 a;
     uint256 b;
   }

   Abc xyz;

   string memName = 'a';

   function set() external {
     xyz = Abc(5,10);
   }

   function get() external view returns(uint256) {
     return xyz.a;
   }
}
```

You will get an error if you try to access a struct member through any of the following methods:

```
    return xyz[memName];
    return xyz['a'];
```

The error message is quite explicit:

> TypeError: Indexed expression has to be a type, mapping or array

Which means that notation `xyz[whatever]` is only reserved to types, mappings or arrays, but not structs. Therefore, unless you know in advance the name member of the struct, you won't be able to access it through a variable.